# PDFTron WebViewer - Is there a way to replace the reply box with comment box?

Tags: javascript, html, pdftron

In the PDFTron WebViewer, when clicking the Comment tool in the header and then clicking on the PDF being viewed, the Reply box pops up in the left panel:

[image]

If you click on the 3 dots next to the timestamp and then Click "Edit":

[image]

You get the Comment box:

[image]

Is there a way to have the Comment box show up by default (instead of the Reply box), and have the Reply box permanently hidden?

Looking through the PDFTron WebViewer documentation, I did not find a good way to have the Comment box always show up. The only approach I've found so far is to tack on some JavaScript that appends HTML to the DOM as soon as the left panel comes into view, but this doesn't seem to be too reliable. Perhaps there is some configuration option for this? I had a look at this page: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/hiding-elements but the Reply box does not have a `data-element` attribute, so it seems you can't hide it in this way.

Also, the Reply box and the Comment box seem to differ slightly in how they send annotations back to the server, so simply editing the text of the Reply box and button to say "Comment" instead doesn't seem like an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new version of PDFTron WebViewer 6.0, we actually improved this behaviour.

If you add the comment, you are automatically taken to the comment.
[Adding Comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsuTV.png)

The second action, after completing the comment is reply.
[Adding Reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkgiI.png)

If you are not the author, the only option is to reply.

You can download the latest from here: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/download/web 6.0 and up.

If you ever want to take a look at the UI code, and modify, we open source the UI here: https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-ui.